# refactor react code to check state null condition

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have working react-native code as sample below, I plan to refactor for readable reason, basically I need to check if state.room has content then return Text with then content of field

```
return (
  { state.room ? 
    <Text>{state.room.name}</Text>
    : null }
  { state.room ? 
    <Text>{state.room.address}</Text>
    : null }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `{ state.room && <Text>{state.room.name}</Text> }` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check that `state.room` is truthy before you are trying to touch it once before the return statement and then assume it is fine.

```
if (!state.room) {
    return null;
}

return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <Text>{state.room}</Text>
        <Text>{state.room.address}</Text>
    </React.Fragment>
)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I have another codes and cannot directly return

Comment: So please help me to understand what is your question better.

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply check write as

```
return state.room && (
    <>
        <Text>{state.room.name}</Text>
        <Text>{state.room.address}</Text>
    </>
)
```

If fragment shorthand is not supported, you can write as `React.Fragment` instead of `<>`.

It will return only render the markup if `state.room` is not falsy.